# How to test a spring mvc controller

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I have the following controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @Resource(name="returnGraph")
    Graph returnGraph;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String goToHomePage(HttpSession session){
        session.setAttribute("sm", returnGraph.getVertexes());
        return "home";
    }
}
```

I tried the following j unit test but it didnt work:

```
public class HomeControllerTest {

    @Mock
    Graph returnGraph;
    @Mock
    Map<String,Vertex> vertexes;
    @Mock
    HttpSession session;

    HomeController homeController;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        homeController = new HomeController();
    }

    @Test
    public void testgoToHomePage(){
        when(returnGraph.getVertexes()).thenReturn(vertexes);
        assertEquals("home", homeController.goToHomePage(session));
    }
}
```

It says I have null pointer exception at.

```
session.setAttribute("sm", returnGraph.getVertexes());
```

However I am not sure why? I am not sure what more I can do about this, how exactly do I deal with the session.setAttribute.

Comment: Two quick points.  If `HomeController` is the point you're attempting to inject mocks into, you should annotate with `@InjectMocks`.  Secondly, try using `doReturn(vertexes).when(returnGraph).getVertexes();` instead of the similar call you have.

Comment: It says: The method doReturn(Map<String,Vertex>) is undefined for the type HomeControllerTest

Comment: You `static import` the method (like you have with `when`).  `import static org.mockito.Mockito.doReturn;`

Comment: And you almost *certainly* want to add that object to the model, not the session.

Answer (score 2):

You may try the Spring MVC Test Framework, here is the [current documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html) or [archive documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20161115070456/http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-mvc-test-framework)

You can test your controller like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public abstract class HomeControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext context;

    @Resource(name="returnGraph")
    Graph returnGraph;

    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testgoToHomePage(){
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/")
           .andExpect(status().isOk())
           .andExpect(content().string("home"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class HomeControllerTest {

@Mock
Graph returnGraph;

@Mock
Map<String,Vertex> vertexes;

@Mock
HttpSession session;

@InjectMocks
HomeController homeController;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);


}

@Test
public void testgoToHomePage(){
    when(returnGraph.getVertexes()).thenReturn(vertexes);
    assertEquals("home", homeController.goToHomePage(session));
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use these annotations: `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`, `@WebAppConfiguration`

If using JavaConfig: `@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyWebConfig.class)`

A complete working example : http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/spring-mvc-unit-testing/